# How can I get sysdate formatted as YYYY/MM/DD and still be a date?

Tags: oracle, date, format

When I run this code:

```
select trunc(TO_DATE(sysdate,'YYYY/MM/DD'),'Day')-43 from dual
```

Oracle returns:

```
28/06/0027
```

I am using `'Day'` for the trunc argument because I want go back 43 days from the beginning of the week. I need the data format to be 2015/07/11, and the data to be typed as a date, not char or anything else. I need this because I am using the date to filter on a table with a date column in the YYYY/MM/DD format.

How can I get the above SQL to give out YYYY/MM/DD typed as a date?

Comment: Your requirements don't make sense.  A `date` does not have a format (well, it has an internal binary representation that is not human readable).  A `varchar2` that represents a date has a format.  If you want a `date` data type, you cannot have a format.  If you want a string formatted a certain way, you cannot have a `date`.  If you want a `date`, `trunc(sysdate)-43`.

Answer (score 0):

The date format on how it is viewed is controlled by the parameter NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

Please change it however you want. Try this.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY/MM/DD';
select sysdate from dual;
```

I am not concentrating my answer on the value of which date you want. I have answered the primary question on Formatting.

Please feel free to comment if you need any more assistance.